# Deleting subdirectories and files in a given directory

Tags: perl, file, directory, unlink

I want to delete all subdirectories and files from a directory, but not the directory itself. For examnple, if I pass "Sample" directory in a variable, and "Sample" directory contains three subdirectories and 3 files, I want to delete all that 3 directories and 3 files. In practice, the "Sample" directory can contain many subdirectories and files.

Comment: Use shell with command `find`. That's much simpler, like one liner..

Comment: @Jasonw Perl doesn't _only_ run on UNIX systems...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**ETA:** This is actually in perlfaq5: [How do I delete a directory tree?](http://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-delete-a-directory-tree-)

Use [`File::Path`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Path.html), core module.

```
perl -MFile::Path=remove_tree -we 
    'remove_tree("Sample",{keep_root=>1}) or die $!'
```

The `keep_root` option will cause remove_tree to keep the top directory:

> keep_root => $bool
>
> When set to a true value, will cause all files and subdirectories to
>   be removed, except the initially specified directories. This comes in
>   handy when cleaning out an application's scratch directory.

Comment: +1 `rmdir` function deletes only subdirectories which doesn't contain any files inside, for deleting subdirectories containing files inside you need `File::Path` module

Comment: Thank you very much guys for your precious comments. 
@TLP love you!!!
I modified the code a little bit, but still it works fine

use File::Path qw{remove_tree};
remove_tree("C:/FFFF2",{keep_root=>1}) or die $!